# GEE NDVI time series extraction does not populate CSV file columns

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I am trying to extract a time series of sentinel NDVI data. This script (below) takes a feature collection of points, buffers around them, and collects all available imagery 30 days before each feature date.

**The output should be a CSV file with two additional columns: "NDVIs" and "dates." Each row in these columns will be an array of NDVI and unix dates that correspond to each feature date.**

However, the task does not fill the columns. Instead the resulting CSV has '[]' in both columns. See here:

[image: resulting CSV file]

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

```
########################################################################################
#################            NDVI at locations                ##########################
########################################################################################

import ee
#ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")

table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/ddlawton/LocustDat_500")

def locational(feature):

  end = ee.Number(feature.get('unixdates'))
  start = end.subtract(2592000000) #subtract 30 days (in milliseconds)
##initialize lat and long
  lat = ee.Number(feature.get('latitude'))
  longi = ee.Number(feature.get('longitude'))

##initialize an EE geometry point with lat and long and buffer 
  geom = ee.Geometry.Point([longi,lat])
  buffed = geom.buffer(500)

  #start = ee.Date(1496793600000)
  #end = ee.Date(1528329600000)

  #end = ee.Date('2019-06-01')
  #start = ee.Date('2019-05-01')
  
  ########define date range of interest
  
  fCollectp = l8.filterBounds(buffed)
  fCollect = fCollectp.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end))
  #filterdate range
  
  

  def addDates(image):
    imagep = ee.Image(image)
    setted = None
    nir = imagep.select('B5');
    red = imagep.select('B4');
    ndviImage = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');
    NDVIavgp = ndviImage.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),buffed,scale=30,maxPixels=1e9)
    NDVIavg = NDVIavgp.get('NDVI')
    NDVIdateCap = ee.String(image.get('GENERATION_TIME'))

    tempA = ee.List([NDVIavg,-9999])
    tempB = tempA.reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())#this will filter out a null if the image was not actually over the gauge
    


    NDVISetted = ee.Image(image.set('date',NDVIdateCap).set('NDVI',tempB))


    return NDVISetted
      
  mapC = fCollect.map(addDates)
  agg = mapC.aggregate_array('date')
  aggb = mapC.aggregate_array('NDVI')
  agFeat = feature.set('dates',agg).set('NDVIs', aggb)
  return agFeat


mapF = table.map(locational)


task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(
  collection=mapF,
  description='Locust_outbreaks_jan_23',
  fileFormat='CSV'
)

task.start()
```